Can I use "scroll my feed" to shorten "scroll through my feed"?

I spent the whole night scrolling my facebook feed.

Can we shorten scroll through my feed to scroll my feed?
If not, then is there any other way that I can shorten this phrase? (as I feel that saying "scroll through my feed" is a bit lengthy.)

Odd that you should be concerned about shortening the phrase that describes what you did the whole night.  "I spent the whole night on Facebook"

Scroll can be transitive and intransitive:

TRANSITIVE VERB 8. Computing
to move (text) up, down, or across a display screen, with new text appearing on the screen as old text disappears


INTRANSITIVE VERB 9. Computing
to move text vertically or horizontally on a display screen in searching for a particular section, line, etc.

Hence both scroll through my feed and scroll my feed are possible.

But scroll in this transitive sense means only changing which part of a file or image is currently displayed. It doesn’t (to this American’s ear, anyway) imply looking at (let alone absorbing any of) the content that’s being displayed. So I’d say that scrolling is merely physical (or merely virtually physical) while scrolling through can involve mental. The pair is analogous to sort paperwork and sort through paperwork.
